# Picking 30 random data from data with sample()?

Tags: r

I am stuck.

We are asked to pick 30 random data from our dataset, then replace the picked values with NAs.

I'm stuck at the beginning, using the following function, as it selects 30 random data items from each column, while I want 30 random data picked among the whole dataset.

```
data2[sample(nrow(data2),30), ]
```

I hope you can help me out, thank you for your help/

Comment: `data2[sample(nrow(data2),30), ] <- NA`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to replace 30 random rows?

```
data2 <- iris # as an example

throwouts <-  sample(nrow(data2),30)

data2[throwouts, ] <- NA

print(data2)
```

Do you mean to replace 30 values in random rows and random columns?

```
data2 <- iris # as an example

coords <- expand.grid(1:nrow(data2),1:ncol(data2)) # all the possible values
coords <- coords[ sample(nrow(coords), 30), ]      # take 30 unique ones of all possible values

for(i in 1:30)                                     # erase each of them individually
    data2[coords$Var1[i], coords$Var2[i] ] <- NA

print(data2)
```

Comment: Thank you... but I don't understand what "iris" stands for ?

Comment: `iris` is a sample dataframe that comes with R so one can easily answer questions that come without sample data like yours . I could not try my code without having `data2` so `iris` data was the next best thing at hand. Try `help("iris")` and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and then use my code on your own original data.

Comment: thank you very much, i used your formula and it seems to work. thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. If you find an answer usefull, please upvote it. If you think, an answer solves your own question, feel free to accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be memory efficient, it uses a logical matrix of `FALSE` values and 30 `TRUE` values in random positions to assign `NA`'s.

```
set.seed(2020)
v <- rep(FALSE, prod(dim(df1)))
v[sample(length(v), 30)] <- TRUE
is.na(df1) <- matrix(v, nrow = nrow(df1))
rm(v)
```

This can easily be written as a function.

```
assignNA <- function(x, n){
  v <- rep(FALSE, prod(dim(x)))
  v[sample(length(v), 30)] <- TRUE
  is.na(x) <- matrix(v, nrow = nrow(x))
  x
}

set.seed(2020)
assignNA(df1, n = 30)
```

Tested with the data

```
df1 <- iris
```

Comment: Assigning `is.na(X) <- TRUE` is an interesting idea that never crossed my mind - thanks for that. However, claiming that building `v` in the full size of `df1` was particularly memory efficient does not seem quite right. Albeit its better in that regard  then my deliberately not memory efficient answer. If memory is of particular concern we can certainly do better.

Comment: @Bernhard Yes, claiming it's memory efficient is only true when comparing to `expand.grid`, I should have made that point more clear. Also, I was surprised to see that base R does not have a `is.na<-.data.frame` method. I might write one and post here later.